# Correct placement and syntax of On error go to

Tags: vba, excel

I guess this is a easy one but I can't figure it out.
I have a vba code in Excel which opens a Powerpoint presentation, find a certain type of shape ("Retângulo de cantos arredondados 9" = "Round corner' rectangle") and replace the existing text (MMM/AA) to another (TESTE).

```
Sub replace()

    caminho_pptx = Cells(2, 2).Value
    mes_ano = Cells(4, 2).Value
    cx = "Retângulo de cantos arredondados 9"

    Set ObjPPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    Set ObjPresentation = ObjPPT.Presentations.Open("" & caminho_pptx & "")

For i = 1 To ObjPresentation.Slides.Count

ObjPresentation.Slides(i).Select

On Error GoTo Prox:

ObjPresentation.Slides(i).Shapes(cx).Select

    If ObjPresentation.Slides(i).Shapes(cx).HasTextFrame Then
        If ObjPresentation.Slides(i).Shapes(cx).TextFrame.HasText Then
            If Obj + Presentation.Slides(i).Shapes(cx).TextFrame.TextRange.Find("MMM/AA") = "MMM/AA" Then
                m = ObjPresentation.Slides(i).Shapes(cx).TextFrame.TextRange.Find("MMM/AA").Characters.Start
                ObjPresentation.Slides(i).Shapes(cx).TextFrame.TextRange.Characters(m).InsertBefore ("TESTE")
                ObjPresentation.Slides(i).Shapes(cx).TextFrame.TextRange.Find("MMM/AA").Delete

            End If
        End If
    End If

Next i

Prox:
Next i

End Sub
```

The problem is that some slides doesn't have this shape, so if `ObjPresentation.Slides(i).Shapes(cx).Select` was not found the program have to go to the next i, but it doesn't work. 
Both syntax of `Prox:` and its position seems to be wrong.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you notice that you have 2 statements `Next i`? Should give you a compile error. Delete the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `On Error Resume Next` statement to assign the shape to a variable, then test if that variable is not `Nothing` before trying to use it:

```
Sub replace()
    Dim oShp                  As Object

    caminho_pptx = Cells(2, 2).Value
    mes_ano = Cells(4, 2).Value
    cx = "Retângulo de cantos arredondados 9"

    Set ObjPPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    Set ObjPresentation = ObjPPT.Presentations.Open("" & caminho_pptx & "")

    For i = 1 To ObjPresentation.Slides.Count

        ObjPresentation.Slides(i).Select

        On Error Resume Next
        Set oShp = ObjPresentation.Slides(i).Shapes(cx)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not oShp Is Nothing Then
            With oShp
                If .HasTextFrame Then
                    If .TextFrame.HasText Then
                        If Obj + .TextFrame.TextRange.Find("MMM/AA") = "MMM/AA" Then
                            m = .TextFrame.TextRange.Find("MMM/AA").Characters.Start
                            .TextFrame.TextRange.Characters(m).InsertBefore ("TESTE")
                            .TextFrame.TextRange.Find("MMM/AA").Delete

                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End With
            Set oShp = Nothing
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```